# How to input a string when Django start up?

Tags: python, django

I need to save a string as password when Django startup. The password must always keep in memory if Django not shutdown. When some request come up, the password will be used to decrypt something. How to input this string when the Django start?

Comment: "Memory" is a relative concept when it comes to web applications. Where do you plan storing that when there are more than one Django processes running in production, possibly on different servers? I could suggest writing a management command that asks for a password and stores it in Django cache framework (memcached, for example).

Comment: You can use AppConfig.ready method to hold the logic, this method will be executed by django initialization code, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready. But trying to read stdin from there won't work.

Comment: Secrets are usually supplied as [environmental variables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

Comment: @Selcuk good idea

Comment: @KlausD. The application will be deployed to other company. I can't keep the secret in a file like environmental variables

Comment: If you don't trust the other company then you shouldn't enter your secrets on their machines.

Comment: @KlausD. This may not help, but it can increase the difficulty of cracking more or less.

Comment: Please explain how it would do that! (spoiler: it doesn't.)

Comment: @geckos Finally, I use your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @user3130007 I'm glad that worked! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of storing the password in a session variable like so: `request.session[‘password’] = ‘YOUR PASSWORD’`. I’m thinking you can do that on your opening view.

You can then retrieve it anywhere using request: `request.session[‘password’]`.

Feel free to read more in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/).
Hope this helps!